# Select Stored Procedure priting a sum column on every row. Should only be on one

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query that lists all the parts for a specified job with their price. I have a total sum column that I only want to print once but it calculates the total every row. I can't figure out a solution? I've added an image of an example result set. I want the 318 to appear in the last row only. Is this possible?

```
use SBS

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects  
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'partPrices') 
              AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE partPrices
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE partPrices
    (@job_name VARCHAR(30),
     @job_type_id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   
        job.job_name, job_type.job_type_desc, 
        distributor.distributor_name, 
        part.part_name, part.price,
        Total_part_price = (SELECT SUM(part.price) FROM part)
    FROM     
        job 
    INNER JOIN 
        job_type ON job.job_type_id = job_type.job_type_id
    INNER JOIN 
        part ON job.job_id = part.job_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        distributor ON part.distributor_id = distributor.distributor_id
    WHERE
        job.job_name LIKE '%' + @job_name + '%' 
        AND job_type.job_type_id = @job_type_id
    GROUP BY 
        job.job_name, job_type.job_type_desc, part.part_name, 
        part.price, distributor.distributor_name
END
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYf8q.png)

Comment: Are you still in need of help?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT job.job_name,
       job_type.job_type_desc,
       distributor.distributor_name,
       part.part_name,
       part.price,
       CASE
           WHEN LAG(part_name) OVER(PARTITION BY part.part_name ORDER BY part_name) IS NULL
           THEN NULL
           ELSE SUM(part.price) OVER(PARTITION BY part.part_name)
       END total
FROM job
     INNER JOIN job_type ON job.job_type_id = job_type.job_type_id
     INNER JOIN part ON job.job_id = part.job_id
     INNER JOIN distributor ON part.distributor_id = distributor.distributor_id
WHERE job.job_name LIKE '%'+@job_name+'%'
      AND job_type.job_type_id = @job_type_id
GROUP BY job.job_name,
         job_type.job_type_desc,
         part.part_name,
         part.price,
         distributor.distributor_name;
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  I was thinking I should put null.  I just ran this query and every column in the totalprice was NULL..